# GetObject(, "Word.Application") does not recognise running Word Application(docm or doc) on UFT 15

Tags: vba, ms-word, hp-uft

I have a requirement where the word is generated from the windows application. I use the

```
GetObject(, "WordApplication")
```

but it does not work and the count of documents returned is 0.

Is there any way to this apart from this way. Also I do not now where the word file is saved by application, that is why I want to take the instance of it and save it to desired location

Comment: Is the missing dot a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following code which starts Word (if it is not already running).:

```
Set wrd = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 
wrd.Visible = True
```

To use Automation (formerly OLE Automation) to control Word from another application, use the Microsoft Visual Basic `CreateObject` or `GetObject` function to return a Word `Application` object.

You may find the [Communicating with Other Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/communicating-with-other-applications) page helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@Eugene Astafiev is correct.

Quick addendum to support.

His answer and this works fine in VB. However, The UFT IDE does not like the empty parameter and it throws syntax errors.

[image: UFT error]

This can be managed by having the `getobject` tucked away in a library and trying not to open it - but that's frustrating.

One solution to this is to wrap the line in a eval statement:

```
Set objWord = Eval("GetObject(, ""Word.Application"")")
```

Or use vbNullString or empty (but not vbEmpty).

Both of these work:

```
Set objExcel = GetObject(vbNullString, "Excel.Application")
Set objExcel = GetObject(empty, "Excel.Application")
```

That opens up the object as such:
[image: excel object in uft]

*Tested in UFT 15.01*